# NgFormModel NgControl read value

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a form where I have already values in the input text field. After the submit button (changes) the unchanged input field returns a empty string in the json object.

```js
//the component

this.builder = fb;

this.EditUserForm = this.builder.group({

  firstName: ["", Validators.required],

  lastName: ["", Validators.required],

});
```

```html
 <form [ngFormModel]="EditUserForm" (submit)="saveChanges($event)">

           <div class="col-xs-2">

             <label for="firstname">First Name</label>

             <input  class="form-control" id="firstname" ngControl="firstName" type="name" required value={{person.firstName}}>

           </div>

           <div class="col-xs-2" >

              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>

              <input class="form-control" id="lastname"  ngControl="lastName" type="name" required value={{person.lastName}}>

            </div>

      

             <div class="container">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>

              </div>                  

  </form>
```

As you can see I have already values in the input. But the ngControl does not take this. Only when I put a change value in the input text field. It shows the value person.firstname but does not read it in ngControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answer would be (with your setup),

You can make use of `[(ngModel)]` directive which actally binds your value to input control and updates `ngCtrl` status.

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" #firstName="ngForm" ...>
```

Look at here working example of the same,

https://plnkr.co/edit/hvAG3lLpfP80U9hMKAEA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `[ngFormControl]` for binding the controls in the template.

```js
//the component

this.builder = fb;

this.EditUserForm = this.builder.group({

  firstName: ["", Validators.required],

  lastName: ["", Validators.required],

});
```

```html
 <form [ngFormModel]="EditUserForm" (submit)="saveChanges(EditUserForm.values)">

           <div class="col-xs-2">

             <label for="firstname">First Name</label>

             <input  class="form-control" id="firstname" [ngFormControl]="EditUserForm.controls['firstname']" type="name" required value={{person.firstName}}>

           </div>

           <div class="col-xs-2" >

              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>

              <input class="form-control" id="lastname"  [ngFormControl]="EditUserForm.controls['lastname']" type="name" required value={{person.lastName}}>

            </div>

      

             <div class="container">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>

              </div>                  

  </form>
```

Comment: That doesn´t work. I got an exception: Can not find control ' '

Comment: `[ngFormControl]="questionForm.controls['location']"` i use it like this and it works. Maybe share more of your code?